# Google translate extension changes text color to black

Tags: frontend, translate

As the color changes to black, then most of the black containers that had white text on it, become unreadable (black on black).

Can I determine if google translate chrome extension is used somehow to change the container color only then?

Any other ideas?

Is there something else to do rather than changing the button colors?